# Flow : redirect to record page when finished

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow, finishlocation

**Situation :**
I have a screen flow that duplicate the record.
What I need is to redirect it to the newly created record(duplicate) when the flow is finished.

**Attempted workaround :**
1 . Created a visualforce and call the instance of flow and modified the finishlocation.

**Code:**
**VFP**

```
<apex:page Controller="AccountFlowController" >
    <br/>
    <flow:interview name="Developer_used" finishlocation="{!OID}" interview="{!myflow}"  >
        <apex:param name="name" value="Test"/>
        <apex:param name="recordId" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class AccountFlowController {

public Flow.Interview.Developer_used myFlow { get; set; }

public String getmyID() {
if (myFlow==null) return '';
    else {

        Account pack = myFlow.Account;
        return (string)pack.Id;

    }
}

public PageReference getOID(){
PageReference p = new PageReference('/lightning/r/Account/'+ getmyID() +'/view');
p.setRedirect(true);
return p;
}

}
```

the code works fine when it is not a screen flow.  But when I added the screen on the flow it failed to start the flow Error : attempted to de referrence null object.

Is there any workaround on this matter?

Comment: VFP
<apex:page Controller="OpptyFlowController" >
    <br/>
    <flow:interview name="Developer_used" finishlocation="{!OID}" interview="{!myflow}"  >
        <apex:param name="name" value="Test"/>
        <apex:param name="recordId" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>

Comment: Controller:
public class OpptyFlowController {

public Flow.Interview.Developer_used myFlow { get; set; }

public String getmyID() {
if (myFlow==null) return '';
    else {
        
        Account pack = myFlow.Account;
        return (string)pack.Id;
        
    }
}

public PageReference getOID(){
PageReference p = new PageReference('/lightning/r/Account/'+ getmyID() +'/view');
p.setRedirect(true);
return p;
}

}